# DIV jumping when scrolling up

Tags: jquery, html, css

please do help me I am getting crazy. I have a menu which has animate= fadeindown and a parallax slider background, my biggest problem is that the title on the slider is jumping when you scroll down and scroll up (take a look at (about.html (WE ARE title - when you scroll up the title is jumping I don't know why this is happening))). Please Help me, thanks is advance.

Comment: Please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If my answer below was helpful please mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In future it would be a bit easier if you could paste the offending code right here in stackoverflow but this is a pretty simple problem and I can understand why it might be difficult to understand where the problem is coming from.

This is a common problem and it's happening because your header `.mainmenu-wrapper` is part of the [regular flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position) but as soon as you apply `position: fixed` (when the user has scrolled a certain distance) it falls out of the regular flow. Absolutely or fixed position elements are taken out of the regular flow so your `.rev_slider_wrapper` is 'jumping' up the page to fill the space left by `.mainmenu-wrapper` when it becomes `position: fixed`.

One way to fix this is to apply a `margin-top` equal to the height of the fixed `.mainmenu-wrapper` class (~180px when viewed on desktop sized devices) to the `.rev_slider_wrapper` class **only** when `.mainmenu-wrapper` has the state of `position: fixed`. This way the vertical space left by `.mainmenu-wrapper` when it leaves the regular flow (that is either `position: fixed` or `absolute`) will be accommodated in your remaining regular flow elements.

You could use something like this in your CSS:

```
.mainmenu-wrapper.stricky-fixed + .rev_slider_wrapper { 
    margin-top: 180px;
}
```

The important bit in the above selector is the `+`. This is the sibling selector and will only apply styles when `.mainmenu-wrapper` **also** has a class of `.stricky-fixed` (when scrolled past a certain point) **and** is a sibling of `.rev_slider_wrapper`

I've just done that very thing in Chrome Dev Tools and while it stops the text from jumping I think you would need to spend some time perhaps playing around with transitions to ensure the application of `margin-top` is a bit more graceful.

Note that this solution is the easiest and quickest as far as minimum amount of code required is concerned. However, you might want to apply a specific class with `margin-top` as a property to `.rev_slider_wrapper` with the same JavaScript/jQuery that is handling the application of the `.stricky-fixed` class. Either way the result is the same.

Comment: I tested your code but the problem is that when I scroll there is a the white space between the menu and slider. Pease help

Comment: function stickyHeader () {
 if ($('.stricky').length) {
  var strickyScrollPos =0;
  if($(window).scrollTop() > strickyScrollPos) {
   $('.stricky').removeClass('fadeIn animated');
        $('.stricky').addClass('stricky-fixed fadeInDown animated ');
        $('.scroll-to-top').fadeIn(500);
  }
  else if($(this).scrollTop() <= strickyScrollPos) {
   $('.stricky').removeClass('stricky-fixed fadeInDown animated');
        $('.stricky').addClass('slideIn animated');
        $('.scroll-to-top').fadeOut(500);
  }
 };
}

Comment: Yeah I think if you have implemented what I said correctly then the jumping is fixed but you can see the white space behind. This is because you have a keyframe animation and that white space is visible before the animation completes. Without changing the animation (which is a little weird when scrolling back up) you could replace margin-top with padding-top and set a background-color on .rev_slider_wrapper to #151515 (same as the header). That way the space still exists but it's now #151515 instead of white.